# SAS converting .sas7bat to JSON

Tags: json, sas, sas-macro

Using **SAS 9.4 M6**, is there an easy way to convert an .sas7bat file into a JSON format?
This is needed inside a STP, so that the JSON can be included in some way in a *proc stream*.

Either have a function/macro which can print the file formatted inside of a *proc stream* or create a sepereate STP which only returns a file as JSON, so that it can be loaded in the background from a web application.

Answer (score 1):

SAS can write JSON in several ways - the two easiest are:

- [PROC JSON](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p0ie4bw6967jg6n1iu629d40f0by.htm) - this allows you to write JSON, within some limited formats.  If the JSON you're writing is pretty simple, this is a very easy way to do it - just pass it a dataset and it will make a single level JSON file with it.  This doesn't work as well if you have complicated structures.

  See also the [PROC JSON Tip sheet](https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/Tipsheet_PROC_JSON.pdf).
- The data step - if you need something more complicated, just write it with the data step!  I've written custom macros before to simplify it - things like `%write_array` to write an array or `%start_object` to start a new object, things like that; but it does get a bit complex.  This is the only way to do truly complex structures, though, beyond what PROC JSON can do.

PROC JSON is as simple as a PROC EXPORT, though... the example from the documentation says it all:

```
proc json out="C:\Users\sasabc\JSON\DefaultOutput.json";
   export sashelp.class;
run;
```

To include it in a stream, you'd either use the `_webout` fileref, or if you really need `PROC STREAM` specifically, you could probably write it to a file, read it into a big macro variable or maybe use %include, and then write it back in during the `PROC STREAM` execution.  But I suspect that you can use `_webout` here and skip `PROC STREAM`.

Here's [an example using PROC JSON with _WEBOUT in a stored procedure](https://support.sas.com/kb/60/964.html).

Comment: Thank you, hopefully the proc json will do the trick already!

Answer (score 0):

proc json is great but it can cause issues sometimes if your data contains invalid characters - in that case you might want to use this macro:  https://core.sasjs.io/mp__jsonout_8sas.html

Fyi, my team built an entire (open source) framework to enable rapid development of SAS-powered web applications - it's called [sasjs](https://sasjs.io)

You can use it to deploy both backend (data) services and even the frontend (as a streamed app).  It works the same on both SAS 9 and Viya, so there are no issues with upgrades.  Further info here: https://sasjs.io/resources/